# SOAP in SWIFT import a Objective C Class

Tags: xcode, swift, web-services, soap

Hi I'm gonna code my application on xCode in Swift, before i had problems with my WebService SOAP in Android, so I did some search and they're a lot of subjects about, but my WebService is particular, look in Android what I did:

```
    SSLConnection.allowAllSSL();

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "SendLead");
    request.addProperty("xml", xml);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportBasicAuth httpTransport = new HttpTransportBasicAuth(URL, getResources().getString(R.string.login), getResources().getString(R.string.mdp));
    httpTransport.debug = true;
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + result);
    SoapObject SendLeadReturn = (SoapObject) result.getProperty("SendLeadReturn");
    String code = SendLeadReturn.getPropertyAsString("code");
```

So I have many constrains:

- http**s** URL
- I have to keep my login to use the other functions of the wsdl (HttpTransportBasicAuth)
- I send and receive xml strings

How to do it, I think it's preferable to import a Objective C class, but which and how please ?